# choosing checkbox echoing submit button immediately

Tags: php, javascript, post, checkbox, submit

what is the code if I have checkbox and by choosing it(without any submit button) showing me a submit button

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<form method="post">
<?php
//what will be the code here?
?>
<input type='checkbox' name='cb'>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: thats a javascript question not a PHP question

Comment: So you want to submit button to appear only if the checkbox is checked?

Comment: when checkbox is checked then show me the submit button

Comment: then without js I can't code it?

Comment: SEE the tags.. u can do it with Javascript and jQuery too

Comment: @negin; i did it with jQUery; will this b fine or u want it in with core JAVASCRIPT??

Comment: I know JUST php but I will accept JAVASCRIPT too I have to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply CAN'T DO without Javascript. With Javascript?

Easy, quick, sweet and approachable

```
<script>
function openinput() {
    document.getElementById('submit').style.visibility = "visible";
}
</script>
<form>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="openinput()" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="go" style="visibility: hidden" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Not a JS guy but something simple like this should work (untested code):

```
<script>
function showHide(obj){
    if(obj.checked==true){
        document.getElementById('submit_btn').style.display = 'inline'; 
    }else{ 
        document.getElementById('submit_btn').style.display = 'none'; 
    }
}
</script>

<form method="post">
<input type='checkbox' name='cb' onclick="showHide(this)">
<input type="submit" id="submit_btn" value="submit" style="display:none" />
</form>
```

Ofcourse there are more elegant solutions using frameworks like JQuery

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, but this will only work if you indeed submit the form but don't do anything with the post values other than this check. JavaScript would be the better option.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['cb'])) {
?>
<input type="submit" value="go power rangers" />
<?php
};
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

raw code: (in jQuery v1.6)

```
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    var $input = $(this);
    if($input.prop('checked')){
       alert('checked');
       $('input[type="submit"]').show();
   }
    else
        $('input[type="submit"]').hide();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PzTNs/)